# Clone() leaves [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: jquery, clone

When I try to clone a certain span element, it shows "[object HTMLSpanElement]" when I click the jQuery onclick button.

This is my code:

**DESTINATION HTML:**

```
<div id="bedragplek"></div>
```

**BUTTON HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:wpbc_to_step(2);myFunction()" id="bedrag" class="btn">Naar volgende stap</a></div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var z = document.getElementById("bedragplek");
var a = document.getElementById("booking_hint14");
z.innerHTML = a
}
</script>
```

What went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You passed something that wasn't a string into something that expected a string. It got converted to a string. Nothing more.

Comment: Don't get it. (I just started to get into script). Can you explain?

Comment: For example, if you did `console.log(a.toString())`, you'll get the same thing that was printed to the page. If you want to append a dom node to another dom node, you'll need to use the appendChild method. innerHTML is for inserting a string containing html into a dom node. Note, however, this will simply move the element, it won't clone it.